# Prevent storing invalid information in sql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have made this form where users can input various information,Everything is fine i am checking for different errors also but the problems is if user inputs email with a invalid email format and when pressing sumbit button it gives error invalid email format which is fine but mydatabase stores the invalid email also,How to prevent storing some invalid information?? And i am new to programming.
Thanks in advance.

```
$nameErr = $adressErr = $emailErr = $passwordErr = $genderErr = "";
$name = $adress = $email = $password = $gender = "";

if(isset($_POST['sumbit'])){
    if (empty($_POST["name"])){
        $nameErr = "Name is required";
    }else{
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
      $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
  }

    if(empty($_POST["adress"])){
        $adressErr = "Adress is required";
    }else{
        $adress = $_POST["adress"];
    }

    if(empty($_POST["email"])){
        $emailErr = "Email is required";
    }else{
        $email = $_POST["email"];
         // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
    }
}
    if(empty($_POST["password"])){
        $passwordErr = "Password is required";
    }else{
        $password = $_POST["password"];
    }

    if(empty($_POST["gender"])){
        $genderErr = "Gender is required";
    }else{
        $gender = $_POST["gender"];
    }
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO users(name,adress,email,password,gender)VALUES(:name,:adress,:email,:password,:gender)";
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindParam(":name",$name);
$statement->bindParam(":adress",$adress);
$statement->bindParam(":email",$email);
$statement->bindParam(":password",$password);
$statement->bindParam(":gender",$gender);
$statement->execute();



?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Boolean` on top

```
$hasError = false;
```

In case of all error, set Boolean true as `$hasError  = true`;

Before sql query :

```
if($hasError){
  // redirect to form page -- pass the ERROR in the url as get and then show the error on form page 
}
else{
 // execute query code
}
```

It's good have server side checks, you can add a lot of validation on client side too.

**Client side checks**

For email, you can use `type='email'` instead of `type='text'`. Similarly, you can have `maxlength`, `required`, etc. to avoid erroneous data.

Answer (score 0):

You first checked all field validation one by one and then executed your insert query. That's why always creating a new rows into database in both cases inputs are valid or invalid. 
you should put your insertion query in the block if only inputs are valid.

Try this -

```
<?php
$nameErr = $adressErr = $emailErr = $passwordErr = $genderErr = "";
$name = $adress = $email = $password = $gender = "";
$error = array();
if(isset($_POST['sumbit'])){
    if (empty($_POST["name"])){
        $error[] = "Name is required";
    }else{
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
      $error[] = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
  }

    if(empty($_POST["adress"])){
        $error[] = "Adress is required";
    }else{
        $error[] = $_POST["adress"];
    }

    if(empty($_POST["email"])){
        $error[] = "Email is required";
    }else{
        $email = $_POST["email"];
         // check if e-mail address is well-formed
            if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
              $error[] = "Invalid email format";
            }
        }
    if(empty($_POST["password"])){
        $error[] = "Password is required";
    }else{
        $password = $_POST["password"];
    }

    if(empty($_POST["gender"])){
        $error[] = "Gender is required";
    }else{
        $gender = $_POST["gender"];
    }
} 
if(empty($error)){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users(name,adress,email,password,gender)VALUES(:name,:adress,:email,:password,:gender)";
    $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindParam(":name",$name);
    $statement->bindParam(":adress",$adress);
    $statement->bindParam(":email",$email);
    $statement->bindParam(":password",$password);
    $statement->bindParam(":gender",$gender);
    $statement->execute();
}else{
    foreach ($error as $key => $value) {
        echo '<li>'.$value.'</li>';
    }
}

?>
```